# Using PageManager API in AEM6/CQ5

Tags: aem, osgi-bundle, sling

My requirement is to iterate over 8000 nodes in the JCR and create a Page object in Java for each node using PageManager API.

To start with I am using PageManager to get the title of a Page as below.

```
public String currentPageTitle(String pagePath) {
    Page page=null;
    ResourceResolver resourceResolver=null;
    PageManager pageManager=null;
    try {
        if (pagePath != null) {
            resourceResolver = resourceResolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
            pageManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class);
            **page = pageManager.getContainingPage(resourceResolver.getResource(pagePath));**
            LOGGER.error("Page $$$$"+page);
            if (page == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Page does not exist: " + pagePath);
            }
        }
    } catch (LoginException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Login Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return page.getTitle();
}
```

Here I am getting page object as null, and it's throwing "Page does not exist: /content/geometrixx/fr.html" when i am trying to pass Geometrixx page URL to get its title.

Comment: Did you pass the path as `/content/geometrixx/fr.html` or `/content/geometrixx/fr` ?

Comment: 1. As rakhi mentioned for resource resolving, don't provide an extension, just the path. 2. You can directly use the path in getContainingPage method, as there is a version with a String as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks rakhi4110 & Thomas ... It did work as per your suggetion.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Extension(.html) and Execute.It will work Fine.
For Iteration over 80000 pages use Recursive function .

```
public String currentPageTitle(String pagePath) {
    Page page=null;
    ResourceResolver resourceResolver=null;
    PageManager pageManager=null;
    try {
        if (pagePath != null) {
            resourceResolver = resourceResolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
            pageManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class);
            page = pageManager.getContainingPage(resourceResolver.getResource(pagePath));
            LOGGER.error("Page $$$$"+page);
            if (page == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Page does not exist: " + pagePath);
            }else{
                buildLinkAndChildren_loop(page);
            }
        }
    } catch (LoginException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Login Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return page.getTitle();
}
public void buildLinkAndChildren_loop(Page page) {
    if (page != null) {
        Iterator<Page> children = page.listChildren();
        while (children.hasNext()) {
            Page child = children.next();
            buildLinkAndChildren_loop(child);

        }
    }
}
```